FIX connection timed-out after successful heartbeat message
I have an application that connects to a server via the FIX protocol. The dependency QuickfixJ 2.3.0 is used. We used Oracle to save the sequence in the quickfix_sessions table since QuickfixJ stores incoming and outgoing sequences in the database.
Recently we switched from Oracle to PostgreSQL, and as a result, we began experiencing time-out problems. The TestRequest was made, and it timed out waiting for the heartbeat response. However, the response was recorded as received in the FIX messages log.
The session finally managed to log back in after the application failed to reconnect and timed out on a logon response that was being logged as received.
We occasionally observe no disconnections during the day, but occasionally they occur twice or three times. There is no consistent pattern for when it disconnects—it can happen in four hours or just one hour. However, the logs show no database issues.
The heartbeat interval is heartbeatInt = 30s
Sample logs:
Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response
Initiated logon request
Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response


You'll probably only get to the bottom of this when you take a thread dump during the period where it is havng problems. Best would be if you took thread dumps regularly to analyse this. QFJ 2.3.x uses a very old connection pool (Proxool) that is no longer maintained, maybe the issue lies there. But hard to tell without a thread dump.

@ChristophJohn: thanks for the response, as you mentioned it maintains old connection pool, so should I use the latest version? or can I put in any custom implementation for the connection pool?

Are you using a stand alone app or e.g. Spring Boot or an application server? If one of the latter, it could be worth trying to use its data source.
https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/discussions/373#discussioncomment-1498176 . QFJ 3.0.0 will use Hikari as connection pool but we don't have a release date. I'd really suggest to also explore the thread dump route to make sure where the problem really is. Could also be that your callbacks have code that might block or hang.

@ChristophJohn: This a standalone application using Spring framework.
